# Align label next to textarea field, centered? pure css solution

Tags: html, css

So I got this snippet:
(this is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eKZAA/))

```
<div><label style="height: 58px;">Label</label>
    <textarea>11111</textarea>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<div><label style="height: 158px;">Label</label>
    <textarea style="height:199px">11111</textarea>
</div>
```

this is the css

```
label{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

This is the sad result:

[image]

I want the label to be in the center of the textarea field. Someone got a clue what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the `vertical-align: middle` property for the textarea (or for any element for which you want to specify a label - e.g. works for multiple select as well).

[Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nLbRD/)

Answer (score 2):

### Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cVkn/7/)

Use `vertical-align` CSS property to set middle value to solve this problem.

#### HTML

```
<div>
    <label>Label</label>
    <textarea>11111</textarea>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<div>
    <label>Label</label>
    <textarea style="height:199px;">11111</textarea>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
textarea{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```